# The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value when registering new user in asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this error when click the `Register` button

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Here is the error line

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I am using Identity that is template of Visual Studio and I have some changes in the `AspNetUser` table. But It it not relative to the `datetime` type.

Comment: You have not shown the relevant code. The error is caused because you have a database field which is DATETIME, but you have a property in your model which is typeof  `DateTime`  and you have not set its value (so its `DateTime.MinValue` (01/01/0001) which is out of range.

Comment: I dont set the row that has datatype is datetime is not null
So why it still required in my registermodel

Comment: Before that, I can register as nomal

Comment: No one can help if you don't show the relevant code. What is your model? What is your controller code?

Comment: You had something that worked. You made some changes, and now it no longer works. You say those changes are unrelated, but don't show those changes. How could anyone possibly give any other input than "you're wrong about those changes being unrelated"?

Comment: I have removed the ApplicationUser in Identity model class because I have created other Entity using ADO.Net.
Maybe has some changes in it
I will check later
Thank you so much

Comment: I dont have computer now, so, I will show code later

Answer (score 0):

make sure datatime value is not January 1, 0001(it is default value),
the value must be greater than January 1, 1753

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a default on ApplicationUser

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

```
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime Registered { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```